# Detach video/audio from NetStream

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, video-streaming, netstream

I wan't to create a Skype-like experience where two persons can communicate by video/audio. Now I want to be able to turn off the video or the audio on the receiving side, meaning I not only want to not display the video or turn down the volume of the audio on the stream, I wan't to make sure the client doesn't stream the data (to save bandwidth). Is this possible?

Let me give an example of what I'm doing now.

**Host**

```
var stream:NetStream = new NetStream(connection);
stream.attachCamera(camera);
stream.attachAudio(microphone);
stream.publish('myStream');
```

**Client**

```
var stream:NetStream = new NetStream(connection);
var stream.play('myStream');
```

On the client I would love if there was a way to tell the stream to detach the video or the audio, like you can attach them on the host side. Something like: `stream.detachAudio()`

Please let me know if I'm going about this the wrong way or there's a different way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that, you can use [`NetStream.receiveVideo`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#receiveVideo()) and [`NetStream.receiveAudio`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#receiveAudio()) like this :

```
ns.receiveVideo(true);      // to receive the video stream
ns.receiveVideo(false);     // to stop receiving the video stream
```

And

```
ns.receiveAudio(true);      // to receive the audio stream
ns.receiveAudio(false);     // to stop receiving the audio stream
```

Of course you can verify that you are not receiving video or audio stream using [`NetStream.info`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#info) :

```
trace('ns.videoBytesPerSecond : ' + ns.info.videoBytesPerSecond);
trace('ns.audioBytesPerSecond : ' + ns.info.audioBytesPerSecond);
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: I totally missed that when reading through the documentation. Amazing, thanks!